# The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I have an android project and i want to use facebook account kit. I did all settings but when i run the project, i am getting this message;

```
E/AndroidRuntime: 500: Initialization error: 503: The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken
```

But i specified it in strings.xml

```
<string name="ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN">***</string>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
        android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
```

Waiting for your helps, thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

For me solution was adding following to the manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
    android:value="@string/app_name"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
    android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
```

And the creating the respective String resources as:

1. facebook_app_id with app id, found at top-left corner next to navigation pane of facebook developer console for your app.
2. app_name which is already defined generally in your string resource file with the name of your app.
3. ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN with value found at Settings>advanced in navigation drawer of facebook developer console. Then go to Security, there you will find "Client Token". Use this client token value for value of this String resource.

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this in string resources (you have to get the app_id)

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">2077942129****</string>
```

and in you Manifest:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Comment: I did it too already but it is not the problem i think. The error is related Client Token. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The Facebook SDKs for Android automatically manages user access tokens through the class com.facebook.AccessToken. You can learn more about obtinaing a user access token by implementing Facebook Login for Android. You can retrieve the user access token by inspecting Session.getCurrentAccessToken.

Answer (score 0):

Check the attached to find to solution click on your products then go account-kit-->settings

[image]